# What does the BEQ instruction do exactly?

Tags: assembly, motorola

I have the following assembly code snippet I am trying to understand. It is assembly for a MC68332 microcontroller.

```
LOOP
    some instructions
    some more instructions
BEQ LOOP
```

I've googled BEQ and I have found it means branch on result zero, but I still don't really understand what it does. Does it compare the result of the last instruction to 0, and if it is 0, it goes back to the LOOP line?

Comment: Can you tell which microcontroller you are referring to?

Comment: the microcontroller is MC68332, thank you

Comment: added an answer, hope it helps.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

On Motorola 68k family, it stands for "branch if equal" which means "jump to given address if zero flag is set" such as when previous comparison is successful.

However, 68332 seems to be different. Based on uppercase syntax, it could be a macro around another instruction which essentially does the same thing.

Assembly programmers who port code from other systems can make use of similar macros to ease the porting process.

Comment: thank you, that's exactly what it does I think. the last instruction before the BEQ is SUB D2,D2 which always set the zero flag. therefore it is an infinite loop. right?

Comment: @jazzybazz yes, sorry for the delayed response :)

Answer (score 2):

The exact answer will depend on which microcontroller you are using.  In general, if there are no operands, BEQ would be expected to branch if the Accumulator is 0.  This is most likely on simple micros where the Accumulator is the primary register for calculations.

Which microcontroller are you using?  You should be able to find a definition for the BEQ instruction in the manual for that micro.

Comment: the MC68332. there is nothing about the BEQ command in the user manual

Comment: what does the verb "to branch" mean?

Comment: Freescale's website has a datasheet, you can find a link to it here: http://www.freescale.com/webapp/sps/site/prod_summary.jsp?code=MC68332.  Branching means to jump to a specific point in the program, in this case to the "LOOP" label.  The function of this code is to loop until the accumulator holds the value "0".